# Rubygems don't load in IRB or Rails Console

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, irb, rails-console

Using RVM on OSX, I'm trying to use ruby gems. However, a

```
require 'rubygems'
```

returns false in IRB and Rails console. Going through similar questions here, I figured it might have to do with the Gem path vs Gem env.

```
MAC-AC028761:Ruby ac028761$ irb
1.9.3-p429 :001 > require 'rubygems'
 => false
1.9.3-p429 :002 > Gem.path
 => ["/Users/ac028761/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429", "/Users/ac028761/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global"]
1.9.3-p429 :003 > exit
MAC-AC028761:Ruby ac028761$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-15 patchlevel 429) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ac028761/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ac028761/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ac028761/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ac028761/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
     - /Users/ac028761/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Both the 'Gem.path' and the GEM PATHS on 'gem env' are the same, so that's not the issue.
Can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Ruby 1.9 `rubygems` is automatically required by the interpreter when it starts, so there is no need to require it again.

```
$ irb
irb> $LOADED_FEATURES.grep /rubygems.rb/
# => ["/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb"]
irb> defined?(Gem)
# => "constant"
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, because I definitely am able to use my gems inside IRB and Rails console, that 'false' was downright misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> require may return false if the file that you are trying to require is
>   already required.